# Remember your users choice in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I am working on an android app and I ask the user a question at first. Lets say male or female.. My app has two different parts, one is for men one is for women. If the user chooses "male", I open the activity for men. I put a checkbox to remember this choice for next time. And when the user opens the app next time I dont want to ask again, just open the activity for men.

I hope it is clear. Here is code piece of related part:

```
View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_menu, null);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                // Shared preferences.
            }
        });
        checkBox.setText("Bu kararımı sonraki girişlerde hatırla.");
```

Can you give me some inspiration? I checked ome questions and articles but I couldnt find an example such as mine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use shared preferences

Comment: really? I am asking how to use it...

Comment: what do you mean by what is data here. What are you referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `SharedPreference` it will store the value and you can use it later and will retain even if the app crashes.

Example :

For storing data

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
prefEditor.putString("MyStore", <Value>);
prefEditor.commit();
prefEditor.apply();
```

For reading from sharedpreference

```
SharedPreferences sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String str = sp.getString("MyStore", "TheDefaultValueIfNoValueFoundOfThisKey");
```

Comment: I know that I should use shared preferences, what is the value here?

Comment: you know that but you need other people to copy/paste you an example from google rather than doing it yourself?

Comment: I explained I couldnt find any solution from google in question. Read it again

Comment: @user2870 you have not checked the docs.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref. the doc has an example.

Comment: @user2870 Now you can copy paste it but keep in mind you shall change the values accordingly

Comment: I think you misunderdtood my question. If I do that, are you sure that it wont ask again male or femal?

Comment: @user2870 YOu will have to check if there is value then do not ask and skip the procedure